# Поиск наибольшего элемента списка

Tags: python

Задача: из данного списка найти наибольшее число.

Я решал так:

```
a = [2,3,4,4,5]
N = len(a)
c = set(a)

for i in c:    # <-- set changed size during iterations
    n = 0
    b = c
    b.remove(i)
    for u in b :
        if i > u:
            n += 1
        if n == N - 1:
            z = i
```

Этот код выдает ошибку set changed size during iterations.

Как исправить?

Comment: А чем вам функция `max()` не угодила?

Comment: нужно было самому написать.

Comment: Я правильно поправил отступы? Исходно в вопросе отступы проглотились редактором и программа была некорректной синтаксически.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как уже было указано в более раннем ответе, функция поиска максимума реализуется за один проход циклом. Соответственно, создание множества также не требуется. Попробуйте придумать такой способ вычисления и реализовать его. Он будет гораздо проще и понятней имеющегося.

---

А теперь про проблемы имеющегося кода:

При выполнении строки

```
b = c
```

вы не создали копию множества, а просто создали новую ссылку на это же множество. Чтобы скопировать множество, можно воспользоваться функцией `set`:

```
b = set(c)
```

---

Насколько я понял, алгоритм состоит в том, чтобы пройтись по всем уникальным элементам и найти такой элемент, который будет больше, чем все остальные. Результат, как я вижу, планируется хранить в переменной `z`.

Проблема в том, что условиие, по которому присваивается значение переменной `z` никогда не сможет быть выполнено, если в списке будет хотя бы два совпадающих значения.

Поэтому, можно изменить условие так, чтобы учитывалось количество элементов в множестве, а не в исходном списке, переменная `N` в этом случае оказывается лишней:

```
if n == len(c) - 1:
    z = i
```

---

Алгоритм теперь формально работает, но всё ещё можно внести несколько улучшений в существующий код:

Можно заметить, что удаление элемента из множества `b` не требуется и можно просто удалить эту строку, не теряя в правильности алгоритма. Действительно, если при итерации нам попадётся текущий перебираемый элемент, то он не повлияет на сравнение и не изменит результат. А раз мы не изменяем множество `c`, то нет смысла и в его копировании. В итоге мы можем удалить и строку создания нового списка, изменив переменную, по которой итерируется внутренний цикл:

```
a = [2, 3, 4, 4, 5]
c = set(a)

for i in c:
    n = 0
    for u in c:
        if i > u:
            n += 1
        if n == len(c) - 1:
            z = i
```

Теперь можно обратить внимание на то, что последнее условие в цикле нет смысла проверять на каждой итерации, и можно проверить его один раз после исполнения вложенного цикла. Также заметим, что если это условие выполнилось, то максимум найден и больше нет смысла продолжать поиски. Перенесём условие на уровень ниже и установим оператор `break`, который прервёт внешний цикл, как только найдётся нужный элемент:

```
a = [2,3,4,4,5]
c = set(a)

for i in c:
    n = 0
    for u in c:
        if i > u:
            n += 1
    if n == len(c) - 1:
        z = i
        break
```

Заметим, что на пустом списке алгоритм не инициализирует переменную `z` и лучше присвоить ей какое-нибудь значение, чтобы пользователь не получил ошибку `NameError` при попытке прочитать найденное значение. Для этого достаточно добавить присваивание `z = None` в начале кода.

```
a = []
c = set(a)
z = None

for i in c:
    n = 0
    for u in c:
        if i > u:
            n += 1
    if n == len(c) - 1:
        z = i
        break
```

Вспомним, что в коде важны имена переменных и таки приведём их в надлежащий вид и вынесем решение в функцию, чтобы можно было переиспользовать код при желании. В случае использования функции от переменной `z` можно полностью избавиться, заменив её возвращаемым значением, плюс оператор `break` преобразуется в `return`:

```
input_list = []

def find_max(lst):
    elements = set(lst)
    for elem in elements:
        lesser_elements_count = 0
        for curr_elem in elements:
            if elem > curr_elem:
                lesser_elements_count += 1
        if lesser_elements_count == len(elements) - 1:
            return elem
```

Дальнейшие улучшения (не касающиеся изменения алгоритма поиска максимального элемента), которые я вижу, связаны с использованием стандартных функций и генераторных выражений. Так как это задание нужно реализовать без использования стандартных функций, то я остановлюсь на последнем варианте.

Comment: Спасибо, за подробный ответ.

Comment: Останавливаться на квадратичном алгоритме не следует -- линейный алгоритм можно  написать, используя только те функции/методы, которые уже используются в квадратичном алгоритме. Можно было бы ещё упомянуть об обработке ошибок, например, о желаемом поведении, если задана пустая последовательность. Также: длинные имена не означают автоматически более читаемый код -- иногда алгоритм яснее прослеживается с более короткими именами (но это мелочь по сравнению с использованием `O(N**2)` алгоритма вместо однопроходного `O(N)`).

Answer (score 1):

Поясню что не так:

1. Эта функция реализуется на одном цикле;
2. У вас `b` стало равно `c`, а потом вы попытались убрать оттуда элемент прямо в цикле перебора элементов `с`. Вот на это вам интерпретатор и высказывает свое возмущение.

Answer (score 1):

Вот простая реализация [`max(a)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max):

```
def my_max(iterable):
    it = iter(iterable)   # получаем итератор
    try:
        max_ = next(it)   # получаем первый элемент
    except StopIteration: # пустой ввод -- нет элементов
        raise ValueError('max() arg has no items')
    for item in it:       # для каждого из оставшихся элементов
        if max_ < item:   # если элемент больше, 
            max_ = item   # он становится новым максимумом
    return max_
```

Можно добавить поддержку `*args` формы и/или `default`, `key` параметров, если необходимо.

Алгоритм является однопроходным поэтому может работать на произвольно большом вводе.